# Align element to bottom of HTML Table Cell

Tags: html, css, html-table, alignment

I have multiple elements in a cell of an HTML table. I want some of the elements to be aligned to the bottom of the cell and some to be aligned at the top. I am having trouble getting the elements to align to the bottom. My table is:

```
    <tr>
        <td style="background-color: #007CE2">
            <p id="t1_list">test<br>another<br>testing</p>
            <input type="text" name="t1_input" id="t1_input">
            <button>
                Add
            </button>
        </td>
        <td style="background-color: #E54040">
            <p id="t2_list"></p>
            <div class="value_input2">
                <input type="text" name="t2_input" id="t2_input">
                <button>
                    Add
                </button>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

However the elements within the div seem to want to stay centered in the cell, rather than stay at the bottom. I have tried two different methods so far with CSS:

```
div.value_input {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

which just takes the div down to the bottom of the page. And:

```
div.value_input2 {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Which has no effect.

I have the code here in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/top8tpe7/6/)

What do I need to do to get the input box and button to align to the bottom of the cell?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to set the parent elements position to relative `position:relative` in order to use absolute positioning. Here is a working snippet.

```css
table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
  }

  table, th, td {
      border: 2px solid black;
        position:relative;
  }

  div.value_input {
   position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
  }
    
    div.value_input2 {
      position:absolute;
      bottom:0;
    }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
   <th style="background-color: #007CE2">
    Test
   </th>
   <th style="background-color: #E54040">
    Test
   </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td style="background-color: #007CE2">
    <p id="t1_list">test<br>another<br>testing</p>
    <input type="text" name="t1_input" id="t1_input">
    <button>
     Add
    </button>
   </td>
   <td style="background-color: #E54040">
    <p id="t2_list"></p>
    <div class="value_input2">
     <input type="text" name="t2_input" id="t2_input">
     <button>
      Add
     </button>
    </div>
   </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
   <th style="background-color: #8BC34A">
    Test
   </th>
   <th style="background-color: #FF9800">
    Test
   </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td style="background-color: #8BC34A">
    <p id="t3_list"></p>
    <input type="text" name="t3_input" id="t3_input">
    <button>
     Add
    </button>
   </td>
   <td style="background-color: #FF9800">
    <p id="t4_list"></p>
    <input type="text" name="t4_input" id="t4_input">
    <button>
     Add
    </button>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need `height:somepx` for vertical align to work in this.

Answer (score 2):

Make the table cell position: relative, and then you can try position: absolute on the div again...

```
table tr td {
  position: relative;
}

div.value_input2 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/74wao8v1/)